# VMware + Androidx86 vga=ask missing resolutions

Tags: vmware, android, resolution, vga

I am mounting Android in a virtual machine to debug applications from an environment that I can control more easily.

I have a problem configuring full screen mode (1920x1080).
In this image you can see that when I add the vga = ask command in the grub, I get many resolutions, but not the one I want.

How could I add more modes?

[image]

If I start from a live image (clarify that this is an installation) the option of fullHDx16 appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the solution is to put as Windows 7x64 operating system and disable the efi BIOS to install version 1 of GRUB.

In this case all resolutions appear.